# Visual Studio is moving lines left automatically after I add a semicolon in some situations. Why is this, and how do I stop it from doing that?

Tags: visual-studio

Before:

```cpp
cout << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
     << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" << endl
```

After:

```cpp
cout << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
    << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" << endl;
```

What I would like:

```cpp
cout << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
     << "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" << endl;
```

Turning off adpative formatting in Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced has NOT changed it.

This is for C++, I have not tested with other languages.

This occurs only immediately after putting the semicolon, and not any other special character that I've tried.

I was thinking it may have something to do with how I wrote the output as two lines, because it doesn't happen if it's all on one line.

Comment: I suspect it's just assuming indentation of 4 characters for continuation lines, which is a pretty common formatting convention.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't realize that this was a convention. Can it be edited in settings somewhere?

Comment: I don't know much about the C++ formatting configuration in Visual Studio. But I'd expect everything to be configurable, including whether pressing `;` or `}` reformats the statement/block.